Leak at sink slip joint/drain pipe
I am having a leak where my p-trap tailpiece connects into the drain pipe coming out of the wall.
I’ve tried to replace the washer, slip joint (the one in the picture has a built in washer), also replaced the tail piece and still having a leak. Unsure what could be causing this. Could it be an issue with the actual drain pipe in the wall?

Is that white plastic nut the one that came with the chrome Ptrap?  Most chrome units come with a chrome nut.  Using a nut other than supplied may be the problem.  Some nuts are self sealing and don't require a washer. Using a washer with them will result in a leak.  A disassembly of the piping there and a good clear picture of the inside of the nut and the fitting it goes on could give us a better idea.

Are you certain the tapered washer under the nut is oriented the correct direction?  The tapered part goes into the joint, and the flat part rests against the inside of the nut.

Most likely you just need to tighten up the slip-joint nut with large pliers. Some people (including plumbers) think they only need to be hand tight. I always snug them up with a wrench.

Slip-joint washers come in a variety of styles and some work better than others. The white plastic beveleled washers, including those integral to a plastic nut, that typically come with big-box store drain kits, are at the bottom tier, and will leak if the slightest scratch is present on pipe or washer. There are silicone (or other soft elastomer) beveled washers which are far superior in sealing effectiveness. Even the flat rubber washers that were once standard in metal slip-joints typically work better.

My first impression of that photo is a drip leak coming from the faucet, not from the drain pipe.  The drain pipe is just in the way of an otherwise simple problem somewhere else.
